# When use static members in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

i have a question, When we must use static members in client scripts, such as TypeScript ?

seccond question: What is different between instance members (with new keyword) and static members in client scripts such as TypeScript ?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance is a collection of methods with their own data. Each instance has its own set of data.

```
class Example {
    constructor(public name: string) {
    }

    showName() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

var a = new Example('Sally');
var b = new Example('Jane');

a.showName(); // Sally

b.showName(); // Jane
```

When you use the static keyword, the property or method can be called without an instance and is shared by all calls.